# Mockito Spy calls the actual method of the spied class instead of returning the hardcoded mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Here's my Spy statement

```
OAuthService oAuthServiceMock = Mockito.mock(OAuthService.class);
     Mockito.doReturn(oAuthServiceMock).when(inviteServiceSpy.buildOAuthService(RESOURCE_URL, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET));
```

Here's the method in the actual class

```
  public OAuthService buildOAuthService(String RESOURCE_URL, String CONSUMER_KEY, String CONSUMER_SECRET) {
        return new ServiceBuilder()
                .provider(new DummyOAuth1ApiProvider(RESOURCE_URL))
                .apiKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
                .apiSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
                .signatureType(SignatureType.Header).debug().build();
    }
```

Here's a snippet of my test case and the instantiation of the actual spied class (which holds the above method)
Setup:

```
//This is in Setup/@Before method
myServiceSpy = Mockito.spy(new myServiceImpl());
```

Test case:

```
 @Test
    public void testGetmyInviteData() throws Exception {
       assertNotNull(myServiceSpy.getmyInviteData(signup_token,CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,RESOURCE_URL, RESOURCE_URL));
    }
```

The problem is that instead of the spy returning the mocked object, the actually method appears to be called throwing a nullpointer exception. Here's the exception I get when I run this test. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong and how to make this better and avoid getting the actual method called?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.mycompany.myapp.service.MyServiceImplTest.testGetMyInviteData(MyServiceImplTest.java:143)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mock statement is incorrect. [It should be](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12):

```
doReturn(oAuthServiceMock).when(inviteServiceSpy).buildOAuthService(RESOURCE_URL, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
```

What's happening in your code is that the `buildOAuthService` is really getting called, which results in your exception.