# Mockito spy is calling the actual class instead of setting the mock when using Guice's Transactional

Tags: java, testing, mockito

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33043458/mockito-spy-calls-the-actual-method-of-the-spied-class-instead-of-returning-the) but the solution is not working. There is a problem with mockito and Guice

```java
package mock
import com.google.inject.persist.Transactional;
import lombok.NonNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeClass {
    public int A() {
        ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        return this.B(objects);
    }

    @Transactional
    public int B(@NonNull List<Object> someList) {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want to unit test A and check the parameters that calls B with. Hence I do:

```
@Test
void someTest() {
    SomeClass obj = GuiceConfig.getInjector()
            .getInstance(SomeClass.class);
    SomeClass objSpy = Mockito.spy(obj);
    ArgumentCaptor<List<Object>> captor =
            ArgumentCaptor
                    .forClass(List.class);

    // when(objSpy.B(captor.capture())).thenReturn(1);
    doReturn(0).when(objSpy).B(captor.capture());
}
```

Instead of mocking B, it is calling the actual implementation of B with null and raising a NPE. In the aforementioned question it was suggested that using doReturn would fix this issue, because using `when(objSpy.B(captor.capture)).thenReturn(0)` would execute the underlying method. Note, if I don't use @Transactional then it works (where as when call fails)

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling method A in your test? Make sure you don't call the method on obj reference, but on objSpy

Comment: @Vladimir yes, I'm calling A on objSpy, but it doesn't even reach that part. B is called before on the doReturn

Comment: Actually it might be because your are calling method B with this reference, and the proxy created by mockito does not know to call the stubbed method, but instead calls the real one.

Comment: @Vladimir that could indeed happen, but when I follow the debugger it calls the method with null on the when, it does not reach the moment that I call A

Comment: `Spy` will always call your actual method. use `Mockito.mock(SomeClass.class)`

Comment: @SSK I want to have a partial spy, something that calls the actual method on A but the fake method on B. See this link for example https://medium.com/@sudarshan_sreenivasan/using-mockito-to-partially-mock-a-class-bf0be6c33dcc

Comment: Could you please add your test class, what you have tried?

Comment: @SSK I've added a full reproducible example, indeed there was a bit more. Without Guice interaction it works